# How to write sql query to get data which the best matches with data in database

Tags: sql, database

I work on AI chat bot.
I need sql query to select a single row from database where user input and text in database best matches. (also match percentage > %80)

For Example: 
"Hello" and "Hello!" , "Hi how are you" and "how are you?", "What is your name?" and "Wat is your name?"

My purpose is to get answer in case of clerical errors. Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Bot LINK: http://developersland.net/chatbot/jessica.html

Comment: Which RDBMS?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: you can achive first two conditions using Where yourcol like %yourtext%, but for last one I dont think so you can do it by query.

Comment: You'll need to make the exact algorithm yourself.  Something that may help you is `SOUNDEX()`.

Comment: yeah you have to make an algorithm for that that calculates match percentage by character sequence. Try to find out an API would be easy for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search a levenstein distance algoritm implementation on google (like [this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552)) and then

```
select text 
from mytable 
where levenshtein_ratio(text, 'text_to_compare') > 80 
limit 1
```

Comment: Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151581/error-while-using-user-defined-functions-mysql

Comment: and if that implementation have bugs, you can find another on stackoverflow. Search `mysql string distance`. Levenshtein is not the only one distance.