# Error while using user defined functions MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, levenshtein-distance

Hi please help me to solve this problem thanks in advance
I defined these functions in database

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
    -- max strlen=255
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
    IF s1 = s2 THEN
      RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s2_len;
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s1_len;
    ELSE
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
      END WHILE;
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO
          SET c = c + 1;
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN 
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
          END IF;
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
            IF c > c_temp THEN 
              SET c = c_temp; 
            END IF;
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
      END WHILE;
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
  END;
```

**and helper function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_ratio( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT;
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2);
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN 
      SET max_len = s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      SET max_len = s2_len; 
    END IF;
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100);
  END;
```

Now I'm trying to write query using these functions:

My Query:

```
SELECT cevap
FROM `chat`
WHERE levenshtein_ratio( soru,"Hello" ) >80
LIMIT 1 ;
```

**My chat table has only two columns Varchar(250) "soru" and "cevap"**

I get following error when I execute my query

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't there be `'Hello'` instead of `"Hello"`?

Comment: Yes, single, double and backquotes means different things, you can even choose: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Comment: there is no any difference when I use ' isntead of " @AndriusNaruševičius

Comment: It cannot be the truth. Maybe for this case you got lucky, but as you see, it is not me only who tell you that :)

Comment: Since when is it assumed that the `ANSI_QUOTES` mode is turned on in MySQL by default?

Comment: I turned on ANSI_QUOTES mode @lanzz

Comment: Are you showing all the code? Typically you have to change the delimiter, which is semi-colon by default. Do a `delimiter //` at the start of the code, then `//` to end the code.